# store and retrieve a class object in shared preference

Tags: android, object, sharedpreferences

In Android can we store an object of a class in shared preference and retrieve the object later?

If it is possible how to do it? If it is not possible what are the other possibilities of doing it?

I know that serialization is one option, but I am looking for possibilities using shared preference.

Comment: I add a helper library in case someone need it: https://github.com/ionull/objectify

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Comment: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39435730/6561141) to similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Android SharedPreferences save/store object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object)

Comment: You can use this library which has lot of feautres inbuilt.
https://github.com/moinkhan-in/PreferenceSpider/

Comment: Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not possible.

You can only store, simple values in SharedPrefences [SharePreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

What particularly about the class do you need to save?

Comment: Thanks.I want to store some data members of the class.And i don't want to store each values of data members using shared preference.I want to store it as an object.If not shared preference what are my other options?

Comment: Serialise it and store it, in a database (SQLite) / in a flat file.

Comment: The answer is not complete. The possible solution is to transform the pojo into ByteArrayOutPutStream and save as String in the SharedPreferences

Comment: another option is saved it as json and then map it back. With GSON or jackSON is really easy

Comment: We can serialize the object and store to shared Preference.

Comment: Why is this marked as the correct answer? The other ones give an actual solution, this one just says "NO"...

Comment: let me get my time machine back to 2011 and figure that out

Comment: You can use this library which has lot of feautres inbuilt.
https://github.com/moinkhan-in/PreferenceSpider/

Comment: @AlejandroBertinelli Because this is the correct answer to the original question. Alexander said he already knew he can serialize an object and then store a string in the preferences. Well, if you first transform an object to a JSON, binary or other string format, probably using a 3rd party library, you can do it. But that's not the same as if the Android API would offer some possibility to store an object.

Answer (score 332):

Yes we can do this using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Download Working code from [GitHub](https://github.com/pchauhan/StoreandRetrieveObjectClassDemp)

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

For save

```
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObject); // myObject - instance of MyObject
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

For get

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

### Update1

The latest version of GSON can be downloaded from [github.com/google/gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

### Update2

If you are using Gradle/Android Studio just put following in `build.gradle` dependencies section -

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: not working in my case. Even after putting jar in libs and setting in build path, Gson class not getting resolved.

Comment: Clean project then try @ShirishHerwade

Comment: @parag that also not working. Can you please tell me steps to use that  jar to remove above error. Because I successfully added that jar in libs folder and then in "java build path" also tried to add externally storing json on my desktop

Comment: @ShirishHerwade download working code http://www.mediafire.com/download/iued27pf025e1uw/GSonDemo.rar

Comment: This answer would be even better if it also mentioned its limitations. What kind of object can and can't we store and retrieve in this manner? Obviously it will not work for all classes.

Comment: `String json = gson.toJson("MyObject");` should be the object not a String.

Comment: One important note should be taken when use this way: Date object won't be stored precisely ( millisecond will be ignored ) the reason is that Date object will be represented by toString() implicitly where no millisecond counted... so strongly I'd recommend to use long to represent time instead of Date object...

Comment: This has a problem with circular reference that leads to StackOverFlowException xD
 Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209959/gson-tojson-throws-stackoverflowerror

Comment: what to set when trying to save it as generic . Class<T> obj = gson.fromJson(json, Class<T>.class); .

Comment: It seems android Marshmallow throw Runtime Exception for this procedure. (Happen on release mode with debuggable false.)

Comment: @SarithNOB should work because not depend on any OS just we are storing string

Comment: @ParagChauhan Oh yes, I see the problem is about converting empty string to object. Default value string getting from preference must "{}" when it is empty. Because "{}" is empty json object.

Comment: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, *it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.*

Comment: @ParagChauhan Yes, that is it. After use default empty value as "{}", there is no more Runtime Exception anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 44):

we can use Outputstream to output our Object to internal memory. And convert to string then save in preference. For example:

```
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
    ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput;
    try {
        objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(arrayOutputStream);
        objectOutput.writeObject(object);
        byte[] data = arrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        objectOutput.close();
        arrayOutputStream.close();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream b64 = new Base64OutputStream(out, Base64.DEFAULT);
        b64.write(data);
        b64.close();
        out.close();

        ed.putString(key, new String(out.toByteArray()));

        ed.commit();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when we need to extract Object from Preference. Use the code as below

```
    byte[] bytes = mPrefs.getString(indexName, "{}").getBytes();
    if (bytes.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    Base64InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    ObjectInputStream in;
    in = new ObjectInputStream(base64InputStream);
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject) in.readObject();
```

Comment: Hi, I know this was posted a while ago, but are you sure the code you have for extracting the stored object is correct? I'm getting multiple errors on the last 2 lines whining about how explicit constructors need to be defined rather than simply having "new ObjectInputStream(byteArray)". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I'm suddenly getting an EOFException on in = new ObjectInputStream(base64InputStream); I'm writing it to shared prefs in exactly the same way you are doing. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have any exception when you write Object to pref? 

From SDK:Thrown EOFException when a program encounters the end of a file or stream during an input operation.

Comment: Kudos, this is the best solution I came across for this problem so far. No dependencies. However, it should be noted that in order to be able to use ObjectOutput/InputStream for an object, the said object and all custom objects within it must implement the Serializable interface.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, here's my solution:

I have class `MyClass` and `ArrayList<MyClass>` that I want to save to Shared Preferences. At first I've added a method to `MyClass` that converts it to JSON object:

```
public JSONObject getJSONObject() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("id", this.id);
        obj.put("name", this.name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then here's the method for saving object `ArrayList<MyClass> items`:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("some_name", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();

Set<String> set= new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    set.add(items.get(i).getJSONObject().toString());
}

editor.putStringSet("some_name", set);
editor.commit();
```

And here's the method for retrieving the object:

```
public static ArrayList<MyClass> loadFromStorage() {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("some_name", 0);

    ArrayList<MyClass> items = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

    Set<String> set = mPrefs.getStringSet("some_name", null);
    if (set != null) {
        for (String s : set) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                Long id = jsonObject.getLong("id"));
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                MyClass myclass = new MyClass(id, name);

                items.add(myclass);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Note that `StringSet` in Shared Preferences is available since API 11.

Comment: Solved my problem. I want to add something. For first use we must check if the set is null. if (set != null){ for (String s : set) {..}}

Comment: @xevser I've added null check as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Using Gson Library:**

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

**Store:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//Your json response object value store in json object
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
//Convert json object to string
String json = gson.toJson(jsonObject);
//Store in the sharedpreference
getPrefs().setUserJson(json);
```

**Retrieve:**

```
String json = getPrefs().getUserJson();
```

Comment: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Using this object --> [TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) its very simple.
you can save most of the commonly used objects with it like arrays, integer, strings lists etc

Comment: Cool, but I think this just works for primitie types (String, double, int, etc) not for custom objects (POJOS)

Comment: it now works for custom objects, check the ReadMe, it has been updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Complex Preferences Android - by Felipe Silvestre](https://github.com/fsilvestremorais/android-complex-preferences) library to store your custom objects.
Basically, it's using GSON mechanism to store objects.

To save object into prefs:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("Felipe");
user.setAge(22); 
user.setActive(true); 

ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(
     this, "mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
complexPreferences.putObject("user", user);
complexPreferences.commit();
```

And to retrieve it back:

```
ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(this, "mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
User user = complexPreferences.getObject("user", User.class);
```

Comment: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You could use GSON, using Gradle Build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Then in your code, for example pairs of string/boolean with Kotlin :

```
        val nestedData = HashMap<String,Boolean>()
        for (i in 0..29) {
            nestedData.put(i.toString(), true)
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val jsonFromMap = gson.toJson(nestedData)
```

Adding to SharedPrefs :

```
        val sharedPrefEditor = context.getSharedPreferences(_prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        sharedPrefEditor.putString("sig_types", jsonFromMap)
        sharedPrefEditor.apply()
```

Now to retrieve data :

```
val gson = Gson()
val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(_prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val json = sharedPref.getString("sig_types", "false")
val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, Boolean>>() {}.type
val map = gson.fromJson(json, type) as LinkedTreeMap<String,Boolean>
for (key in map.keys) {
     Log.i("myvalues", key.toString() + map.get(key).toString())
}
```

Comment: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Common shared preference (CURD)
SharedPreference: to Store data in the form of value-key pairs with a simple Kotlin class.

```
var sp = SharedPreference(this);
```

Storing Data:

To store String, Int and Boolean data we have three methods with the same name and different parameters (Method overloading).

```
save("key-name1","string value")
save("key-name2",int value)
save("key-name3",boolean)
```

Retrieve Data:
To Retrieve the data stored in SharedPreferences use the following methods.

```
sp.getValueString("user_name")
sp.getValueInt("user_id")
sp.getValueBoolean("user_session",true)
```

Clear All Data:
To clear the entire SharedPreferences use the below code.

```
 sp.clearSharedPreference()
```

Remove Specific Data:

```
sp.removeValue("user_name")
```

Common Shared Preference Class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class SharedPreference(private val context: Context) {
    private val PREFS_NAME = "coredata"
    private val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    //********************************************************************************************** save all
    //To Store String data
    fun save(KEY_NAME: String, text: String) {

        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, text)
        editor.apply()
    }
    //..............................................................................................
    //To Store Int data
    fun save(KEY_NAME: String, value: Int) {

        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.putInt(KEY_NAME, value)
        editor.apply()
    }
    //..............................................................................................
    //To Store Boolean data
    fun save(KEY_NAME: String, status: Boolean) {

        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_NAME, status)
        editor.apply()
    }
    //********************************************************************************************** retrieve selected
    //To Retrieve String
    fun getValueString(KEY_NAME: String): String? {

        return sharedPref.getString(KEY_NAME, "")
    }
    //..............................................................................................
    //To Retrieve Int
    fun getValueInt(KEY_NAME: String): Int {

        return sharedPref.getInt(KEY_NAME, 0)
    }
    //..............................................................................................
    // To Retrieve Boolean
    fun getValueBoolean(KEY_NAME: String, defaultValue: Boolean): Boolean {

        return sharedPref.getBoolean(KEY_NAME, defaultValue)
    }
    //********************************************************************************************** delete all
    // To clear all data
    fun clearSharedPreference() {

        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()
    }
    //********************************************************************************************** delete selected
    // To remove a specific data
    fun removeValue(KEY_NAME: String) {
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.remove(KEY_NAME)
        editor.apply()
    }
}
```

Blog:
https://androidkeynotes.blogspot.com/2020/02/shared-preference.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Create Public class 

public class Prefs {

    //Single Instance object
    private static Prefs instance = null;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreference = null;


    //Single Instance get
    public static Prefs getPrefInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Prefs();
        return instance;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    private void openPrefs(Context context) {
        sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(Const.PREFS_FILENAME,
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setValue(Context context, String key, String value) {
        openPrefs(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEdit = sharedPreference.edit();
        prefsEdit.putString(key, value);
        prefsEdit.commit();
        prefsEdit = null;
        sharedPreference = null;
    }

    public String getValue(Context context, String key, String value) {
        openPrefs(context);
        String result = sharedPreference.getString(key, value);
        sharedPreference = null;
        return result;
    }

    public void remove(Context context, String key) {
        openPrefs(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreference.edit();
        prefsEditor.remove(key).commit();
        prefsEditor = null;
        sharedPreference = null;
    }
}

 2. If you want to store value in SharedPreferences with below line.
 Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(MainActivity.this, Const.GCM_ID, token);

3. If you want to get the value from SharedPreferences.
Prefs.getPrefInstance().getValue(context, Const.GCM_ID, "");

4. If you want to remove the value from SharedPreferences.
Prefs.getPrefInstance().remove(context, Const.GCM_ID);
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to store objects in SharedPreferences, What i did is to create a public class, put all the parameters i need and create setters and getters, i was able to access my objects,

Answer (score -3):

Do you need to retrieve the object even after the application shutting donw or just during it's running ?

You can store it into a database.
Or Simply create a custom Application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Object mMyObject;
    // static getter & setter
    ...
}

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application ... android:name=".MyApplication">
        <activity ... />
        ...
    </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```

And then from every activities do :

```
((MyApplication) getApplication).getMyObject();
```

Not really the best way but it works.

Answer (score -7):

Yes .You can store and retrive the object using Sharedpreference