# Storing session state in android application

Tags: android, session, architecture

I know that the question is rather frequent, but it looks like I have to ask it anyway.

I am developing a network game. The app holds current user's account info, team info, units, private messages etc. to provide a permanent access to them. I've created a class that holds all of those, and now I am loading session data each time on the app startup, showing splash activity. The session data instance lies in the `Application` class  child.

Every time, in every Activity's `onCreate` and `onResume` I check if the session data is alive, and if it is not, I start the splash activity to reload it. I know that the way is a kind of a bad practice, but it looks like the fastest approach to manage session.

Recently, I've started a beta testing for my app and faced a plenty of NPE's in objects targeting session data objects, despite my `onCreate` and `onResume` checks.

Can anybody suggest a better approach to the problem?

Additionally,

- The session data has a huge amount of object types to store, so It will be really tediously to create all databases for them;
- The session data is modified frequently on the server, so it is not a good idea to load everything once and use forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is better solution for this kind of problems ..

the code below show a class that you could use to save and get user data

```
    public class SharedPreferencesClass {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    public SharedPreferences setting;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public SharedPreferencesClass(Context context) {
        setting = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    }

    //Save user data by calling this method
    public void setLoginData(String userId, String userName, String email,
            String image_str, String about) {
        editor = setting.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Login", true);
        editor.putString("UserID", userId);
        editor.putString("UserName", userName);
        editor.putString("Email", email);
        editor.putString("About", about);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //An example of editing some of the user data
    public void setEditedData(String email, String image_str ,String about) {
        editor = setting.edit();
        editor.putString("Email", email);
        editor.putString("About", about);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //this method for clearing all of the user information
    public void clearPerferance() {
        editor = setting.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    //The below methods is for getting specific data that you saved it the shared preference ...

    public boolean isLogin() {
        return setting.getBoolean("Login", false);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return setting.getString("UserName", "");
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return setting.getString("UserID", "");
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return setting.getString("Email", "");
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return setting.getString("About", "");
    }

}
```

Also here is a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) that explain and show how to use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Each unit has about 50 skills, each team has about 30 units, plus account info and something else. Do you really think that shared preferences are the right place to save all of those?

Comment: Aren't shared preferences stored in XML?

Comment: The SharedPreferences as i see its good for saving small amount of data (like account information and other preferences option) and that  not mean you cant save a large amount of data.. but if you really have a large amount of data to be save you must use SQLite Database

...The below link may also help you to find the best storage option depend on your amount of data to be saved.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to store objects to SharedPreferences. As far I know, you can't put object to [**SharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html). So you need to do some tricks. I think this solution will be enough for you:

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To Save

```
 Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson("MyObject");
 prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
 prefsEditor.commit();
```

To Retreive

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

This code is from ***["this quesiton"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object)*** by **MuhammadAamirALi**

Comment: Json is rather slow, isn't it?

Comment: How do you send data from server to client? I suggest that first check how much time does it take if you send a json from server to client and parse it. You can check with Logcat. `Log.w("----DEBUG----", "<current place>")`

Answer (score 0):

Don't start splash screen every time. it will reduce the performance of your application just create one method to load session data and call it when session is not exist. and load the session data in application's shared preferences.

Comment: Why does it reduce a performance? User has to wait about 30 seconds to load session data anyway, doesn't he?

Comment: Every time you start splash screen that will degrade the performance of application. Just check is session active or not if not call the separate method to load session again.