# How to save custom ArrayList by using the SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sharedpreferences

I wanna know how to save custom ArrayList into Android Phone.
Because it used to it at the filter activity.
I should keep this information into anywhere.

```
ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected> mSelectedList = new ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected>();

public class ListAdapterItemsSelected {
    public String  sText;
    public boolean bSelected;

    public String getsText() {
        return sText;
    }

    public void setsText(String sText) {
        this.sText = sText;
    }


    public boolean isbSelected() {
        return bSelected;
    }


    public void setbSelected(boolean bSelected) {
        this.bSelected = bSelected;
    }  

    public ListAdapterItemsSelected(String _text, boolean _selected) {
        sText = _text;
        bSelected = _selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use gson to seralize the arraylist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected> mSelectedList = new ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected>();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(mSelectedList);
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Save to SharedPreferences
sp.edit().putString("KEY", jsonString).commit();

//Get to SharedPreferences

//For default value, just to get no errors while getting no value from the SharedPreferences
String empty_list = gson.toJson(new ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected>()); 

ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected> mSelectedList = gson.fromJson(sp.getString("KEY", empty_list),
        new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListAdapterItemsSelected>>() {
        }.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly support. 
It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is now generic way. You may convert it to string by any methods like using json converters or use third party library like:

[hawk:Secure Simple Key-Value Storage for Android](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk)

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` isn't great for this sort of thing. You can't even easily store a `List` of `String`s without using some nasty hack, let alone a `List` of custom objects. Personally I'd store the `List` as a file in internal storage, using a `DataOutputStream` to write first the size of the `ArrayList`, followed by a sequence of `boolean` and `String` values for your objects.

Comment: well the object might have a `toString()` method

Comment: @Elltz I don't see your point.