# I am trying to save a arrayadapter to sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save a `ArrayAdapter` to shared preferences. I can get one string recovered using this code, but only one, I was not able to recover the entire `ArrayAdapter`.

```
package com.example.eduleito.listacompras;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

  private EditText edt_item;
  private Button btn_limpar;
  private ImageButton btn_adcionar;
  private ListView lst_item;
  private ArrayAdapter adp_item;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    edt_item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_item);
    btn_limpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_limpar);
    btn_adcionar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_adcionar);
    lst_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_item);
    btn_adcionar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_limpar.setOnClickListener(this);
    adp_item = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lst_item.setAdapter(adp_item);

    loadSavedPreferences();

  }

  private void loadSavedPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String item = sharedPreferences.getString("storeditem", "");
    adp_item.add(item);
   }

  private void savePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btn_adcionar) {
      String item = edt_item.getText().toString();
      adp_item.add(item);
      savePreferences("storeditem", item);
      edt_item.setText("");
    } else if (v == btn_limpar) {
      adp_item.clear();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: For saving anything other than primitive data types in SharedPreferences see answers to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object

Answer (score 0):

Google:
[Storage Options on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent **key-value pairs of primitive data types**.