# updating particular item in list

Tags: java, android

I have an list of customer object. I need to read them from shared preferences and check for particular object by id with my new object and replace the old one in list with new object and write it to back to pref. This is what I am doing..Is it right?

```
List<School> schools = readFromPref();
ListIterator<School> iterator = schools.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
School oldSchool = iterator.next();
if (oldSchool.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(newSchool.getId())) {
        iterator.set(newSchool);
        schools.add(newSchool);
    }
}
writeToPref(schools);
```

Comment: @BaluSangem there is difference between List and `listView`

Comment: Oh Sorry my bad @AbdulKawee

Comment: What is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enhanced For loop](https://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loop) to get and update data in your ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<School> schools = readFromPref();
            int i=0;
            for(School oldSchool : schools){  //Enhanced For loop
                if(oldSchool.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(newSchool.getId())){
                    oldSchool.setId(newSchool.getId());
                    schools.set(i, oldSchool);
                }
                i++;
            }
            writeToPref(schools);
```

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object) of how to save and retrive Object from SharedPreference using Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `schools.add(newSchool);` because `iterator.set(newSchool);` is updating your school list already.

And everything looks good

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in form of map where key will be the id of your object,and update the object on key basis