# Android - Typeface Shared Preferences

Tags: android, textview, android-sharedpreferences

To begin I've got an app with 2 activities. 1st is the main one. On the 2nd there are 3 checkboxes that are changing the typeface of textview in main activity (Bold, Italic and Underline). What I want to do is after closing and reopening app the text view has the typeface that was previously selected. 
Is there any way to store Typeface in shared preferences, or it can be done in some other way?

Thanks

UPDATE

This works (third approach from below answer)

```
    boolean loadCheck1 = preferences.getBoolean("checked1", false);
    if (loadCheck1) {
            tx.setTypeface(tx.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        tx.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }

    boolean loadCheck2 = preferences.getBoolean("checked2", false);
    if (loadCheck2) {
        tx.setTypeface(tx.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
    } else {
        tx.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }

    boolean loadCheck3 = preferences.getBoolean("checked3", false);
    if (loadCheck3){
        tx.setPaintFlags(tx.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    } else {
    tx.setPaintFlags(tx.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG));
    }
```

But there is a problem with Typeface Bold. It even if the checkbox1 is checked Bold is not appearing. It is really strange, cause every single If is made in the same way. In addition if I'll change the order (for example loadcheck2, loadcheck3, loadcheck1) then Italic is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use **GSON** library to store `Object` class (`Typeface` extends `Object`) in `SharedPrefereces`. More information about this approach: [How Android SharedPreferences save/store object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object)
- If you do not want to use any external libraries, you could make an `enum` or `interface` class with variables that would represent specific `Typeface` that you want to save and store that variable in `SharedPreferences`. When user reopens the app just retrieve that variable and use `switch` statement to determine which `Typeface` to use.
- Store a value in `SharedPreferences` that represents which `CheckBox` is selected before an `Actvity` is destroyed. Then on start of `Activity` retrieve that value and check which `CheckBox` **was selected**, then choose corresponding `Typeface`.

---

I would recommend using **second** or **third** approach, because storing `Typeface` in `SharedPreferences` might bring some performance drawbacks compared to other approaches.

---

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! But I've another problem. Pleas see updated question.

Comment: I am glad it worked. 
I would suggest you to add some breakpoints and debug your code.

Comment: By the way, your goal is to use few typefaces on one another like: Bold + Italic / Bold + Underline / Bold + Italic + Underline? Or just one? Because at the moment if first 2 conditions are true then second `if` will override first `if`.

Comment: Depends on the selected checkbox (if Bold an Italic selected then text should be Bold and Italic etc). But still no idea why only two of them are working. Previously all of them were working and code was exactly the same.

Comment: Then as I mentioned above, if Bold conditional and Italic conditional are both `true` then second conditional will always override first one. Just use this in second `if`: `tx.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC | Typeface.BOLD);`

Comment: But now when you will only choose checkBox Italic then also Bold will be activated

Comment: Well that is logical. My bad. In that case try adding one more condition between Italic and Undeline: `if (loadCheck1 && loadCheck2) { tx.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); }` and revert my previous suggestion.

Comment: Ok, thanks that worked. 3 additional if's were needed: `if (loadCheck1 && loadCheck2) {
            tx.setTypeface(tx.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        }
        else if (loadCheck1 && !loadCheck2) {
            tx.setTypeface(tx.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        }
        else if (!loadCheck1 && loadCheck2) {
            tx.setTypeface(tx.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
        }`