# Persisting a JSON with mutable lists in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

```
var test = JSONArray()
test.put(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4))
test.put(mutableListOf(2,3,4,5))
```

I would like to persist this var, if possible. But I haven't had any luck using shared preferences.

An alternative would be probably to use internal storage. I wouldn't want to use Room though because of the massive amounts of boilerplate involved (at least in my perspective). How do I persist this in internal storage?

Comment: Save it to a file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object/18463758#18463758