# Make a spinner invisible but still access to his selected item?

Tags: android, null, android-spinner

I would like to know if there is any way to access a spinner selected item while we set it to hidden ? I've tried `spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)` but then the **selected item** is **null**. Looks like this method resets selected item to null :/

The reason I need to do it is because I want the spinner to have a value depending on the user logged in (Spring WS) but then I want only to show the spinner if admin mode is activated. It's not active by default and since I need to access this value from other activities (without adding parameters) I can't manage to find a solution.

Thanks forward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *View.GONE* use **View.INVISIBLE** **or** if you
want to release the space that the Spinner uses, then you must save the latest selected value of spinner in a variable,  **you can use one of the bellow ways:**

1. gson-google https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463758/9944300
2. Also you can use Singleton design pattern [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/9944300)

Comment: Thanks !

I thought of it but the fact that I need to access the item from other activities is a bit complicated. Moreover as you said I need to release the space used by the Spinner. Is there a way to save an Object in preferences or something else that can get carried through the entire application ? Because it seems like you can only store primitives in preferences :/

Comment: EDIT : I just thought of serializing the object in a json string but doesn't seem to be that pretty :/

Comment: I think I'll try to serialize it within a preference, but well it would have been amazing if we could still get a value on GONE visibility :'( Still thanks a lot for your answer !