# What is the best option to store objects for an Android application?

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore, data-storage

I know this is a well-known question (for example: [How do you save/store objects in SharedPreferences on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-do-you-save-store-objects-in-sharedpreferences-on-android)) , but I was wondering if it was better to store an object in shared preferences (using json) or as a static object of an activity (companion object). This is an object that I will use it in almost all the activities and fragments.

For example, I have an User object.

The **first solution** will look like this:

```
val mUser = User(x,x,x...)
val mUserJson = Gson().toJson(mUser)

mSharedPreferences
                .edit()
                .putString(USER_DATA, mUserJson)
                .apply()
```

And for **the second one**, I declared the object on the first activity, and then on another activity I initialized it.

```
class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var mUser: User
    }

}
```

On another activity:

```
FirstActivity.mUser = User(x,x,x...)
```

I don't know if there is a problem with the second solution (efficiency?) but as for the first solution I have to initialized shared preferences for each activity that I'm willing to use the User object (is this too bad?). Also, if I want to change a User variable, I have to reconvert the user object into json and rewrite this preference:

```
val mUserPref = mSharedPreferences.getString(USER_DATA, "")
            .run { Gson().fromJson(this, User::class.java) }

mUserPref.variable = new_value
mSharedPreferences
                   .edit()
                   .putString(USER_DATA, Gson().toJson(mUserPref)) 
                   .apply()
```

So, can someone explain me which is the best solution and why? Thank you :)

Comment: `if it was better to store an object in shared preferences (using json) or as a static object of an activity (companion object)` these storages aren't the same thing, because the one is a only available for the duration of the app. you probably shouldn't even be using sharedPrefs for something like this and rather make use of a proper database, people overuse shared prefs because it's easy to use, but it doesn't make it the best tool for the job

Comment: @a_local_nobody how you would use/create a database to only store one object?

Comment: `how you would use/create a database to only store one object?` lots of resources available online for this and storing a single or multiple values would makes no difference, Room makes storing data easy, point is, do you actually _need_ persistent storage or not ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody it's only for the duration of the app, room is a good solution for this?

Comment: if it's only for the duration of the app, you should probably get rid of shared prefs and just use a companion object or something similar

Comment: If possible [Datastore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) will help.