# gson.toJson() throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, json, object, gson, stack-overflow

I would like to generate a JSON String from my object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(item);
```

Everytime I try to do this, I get this error:

```
14:46:40,236 ERROR [[BomItemToJSON]] Servlet.service() for servlet BomItemToJSON threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:473)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:347)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:440)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:235)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:843)
```

These are the attributes of my **BomItem** class:

```
private int itemId;
private Collection<BomModule> modules;
private boolean deprecated;
private String partNumber;
private String description; //LOB
private int quantity;
private String unitPriceDollar;
private String unitPriceEuro;
private String discount; 
private String totalDollar;
private String totalEuro;
private String itemClass;
private String itemType;
private String vendor;
private Calendar listPriceDate;
private String unitWeight;
private String unitAveragePower;
private String unitMaxHeatDissipation;
private String unitRackSpace;
```

Attributes of my referenced **BomModule** class:

```
private int moduleId;
private String moduleName;
private boolean isRootModule;
private Collection<BomModule> parentModules;
private Collection<BomModule> subModules;
private Collection<BomItem> items;
private int quantity;
```

Any idea what causes this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could happen if you put an object instance inside itself somewhere inside the gson.

Comment: The Exception looses the root cause an starts the log with `JsonWriter.java:473)`, how do identify the root cause of the Gson stackoverflow

Answer (score 98, accepted):

That problem is that you have a circular reference.

In the `BomModule` class you are referencing to:

```
private Collection<BomModule> parentModules;
private Collection<BomModule> subModules;
```

That self reference to `BomModule`, obviously, not liked by GSON at all.

A workaround is just set the modules to `null` to avoid the recursive looping. This way I can avoid the StackOverFlow-Exception.

```
item.setModules(null);
```

Or mark the fields you **don't want** to show up in the serialized json by using the `transient` keyword, eg:

```
private transient Collection<BomModule> parentModules;
private transient Collection<BomModule> subModules;
```

Comment: Yes a BomModule object can be part of another BomModule object.

Comment: But is that a problem? 'Collection<BomModule> modules' is only a collection, and I think gson should be able to make a simple array out of it?

Comment: @dooonot: Do any of the objects in the collection reference their parent object?

Comment: I am not sure if I got you right, but yes. Please see the updated question above.

Comment: @dooonot: As I suspected, it goes into an infinite loop when serializing the parent and child collections.  What kind JSON do you expect it to write?

Comment: I just want to have the moduleIds in the array. Something like this: Json: {"itemId":63788,"modules":[60000, 60001, 60002, 60003],"deprecated":false,"partNumber":"xx-xx-xxxx","description":bla bla bla","quantity":0,"unitPriceDollar":"$350.00","discount":"10%","totalDollar":"$0.00","itemClass":"Server","itemType":"HW","vendor":"Sun"} - any way how to approach this?

Comment: Ass a workaround I just set the modules to null to avoid the recursive looping. (item.setModules(null)). This way I can avoid the StackOverFlow-Exception. Thanks for the hint dude!

Comment: item.setModules(null) made my day :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

I had this problem when I had a Log4J logger as a class property, such as:

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

This can be solved by either making the logger `static` or simply by moving it into the actual function(s).

Comment: Absolutely great catch. That self reference to the class obviously not liked by GSON at all. Saved me a lot of headaches! +1

Comment: another way to solve it, is by adding transient modifier to the field

Comment: logger should mostly be static. Otherwise you will incur the cost of getting that Logger instance for each object creation, which is probably not what you want. (The cost isn't trivial)

Answer (score 29):

If you're using Realm and you get this error, and the object giving the trouble extends RealmObject, don't forget to do `realm.copyFromRealm(myObject)` to create a copy without all the Realm bindings before passing through to GSON for serialization.

I'd missed doing this for just one amongst a bunch of objects being copied... took me ages to realise as the stack trace doesn't name the object class/type. Thing is, the issue is caused by a circular reference, but it's a circular reference somewhere in the RealmObject base class, not your own subclass, which makes it harder to spot!

Comment: That's correct! In my case change my object list queried directly from realm to   ArrayList<Image> copyList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Image image : images){
            copyList.add(realm.copyFromRealm(image));
        }

Comment: Using realm, that was exactly the solution that solves the problem, thanks

Answer (score 14):

As SLaks said StackOverflowError happen if you have circular reference in your object.

To fix it you could use TypeAdapter for your object.

For example, if you need only generate String from your object you could use adapter like this:

```
class MyTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
    public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter writer, T obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.value(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

and register it like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
               .registerTypeAdapter(BomItem.class, new MyTypeAdapter<BomItem>())
               .create();
```

or like this, if you have interface and want to use adapter for all its subclasses:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
               .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(BomItemInterface.class, new MyTypeAdapter<BomItemInterface>())
               .create();
```

Answer (score 12):

My answer is a little bit late, but I think this question doesn't have a good solution yet. I found it originally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43410950/1770778).

With Gson you can mark the fields you **do** want to be included in json with `@Expose` like this:

```
@Expose
String myString;  // will be serialized as myString
```

and create the gson object with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Circular references you just **do not** expose. That did the trick for me!

Comment: Do you know if there is an annotation that does the opposite of this? There are like 4 fields I need to ignore and over 30 I need to include.

Comment: @jDub9 Sorry for my late answer, but I have been on holiday. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889590/1770778) answer. Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

This error is common when you have a logger in your super class. As @Zar suggested before, you can use **static** for your logger field, but this also works:

```
protected final transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

P.S. probably it will work and with @Expose annotation check more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811253/1766166

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. In my case the reason was that constructor of my serialized class take context variable, like this:

```
public MetaInfo(Context context)
```

When I delete this argument, error has gone.

```
public MetaInfo()
```

Comment: I encountered this issue when passing service object reference as context. Fix was to make the context variable static in the class that uses gson.toJson(this).

Comment: @user802467 do you mean android service?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry for my bad, this is my first answer. Thanks for your advises.

I create my own Json Converter

The main solution I used is to create a parents object set for each object reference. If a sub-reference points to existed parent object, it will discard. 
Then I combine with an extra solution, limiting the reference time to avoid infinitive loop in bi-directional relationship between entities.

My description is not too good, hope it helps you guys.

This is my first contribution to Java community (solution to your problem). You can check it out ;)
There is a README.md file
https://github.com/trannamtrung1st/TSON

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Self Promotion Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See:  [What signifies “Good” self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: Thanks so much. I had edit my answer. Hope it would be fine :D

Comment: Similar to what the other commenters said, it is preferred that you show the most important parts of your code in your post. Also, you don't need to apologize for mistakes in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Android users, you cannot serialize a `Bundle` due to a self-reference to `Bundle` causing a `StackOverflowError`.

To serialize a bundle, [register a `BundleTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google-gson/typeadapters/blob/master/android/src/main/java/BundleTypeAdapterFactory.java).

Answer (score 0):

In Android, gson stack overflow turned out to be the declaration of a Handler. Moved it to a class that isn't being deserialized.

Based on Zar's recommendation, I made the the handler static when this happened in another section of code. Making the handler static worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

`BomItem` refers to `BOMModule` (`Collection<BomModule> modules`), and `BOMModule` refers to `BOMItem` (`Collection<BomItem> items`). Gson library doesn't like circular references. Remove this circular dependency from your class. I too had faced same issue in the past with gson lib.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem occur for me when I put:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( this.getClass().getName() );
```

in my object...which made perfect sense after an hour or so of debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid unnecessary workarounds, like setting values to null or making fields transient. The right way to do this, is to annotate one of the fields with @Expose and then tell Gson to serialize only the fields with the annotation:

```
private Collection<BomModule> parentModules;
@Expose
private Collection<BomModule> subModules;

...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the class had an InputStream variable which I didn't really have to persist. Hence changing it to Transient solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some time fighting with this issue, I believe i have a solution.
Problem is in unresolved bidirectional connections, and how to represent connections when they are being serialized.
The way to fix that behavior is to "tell" `gson` how to serialize objects. For that purpose we use `Adapters`.

By using `Adapters` we can tell `gson` how to serialize every property from your `Entity` class as well as which properties to serialize.

Let `Foo` and `Bar` be two entities where `Foo` has `OneToMany` relation to `Bar` and `Bar` has `ManyToOne` relation to `Foo`. We define `Bar` adapter so when `gson` serializes `Bar`, by defining how to serialize `Foo` from perspective of `Bar` cyclic referencing will not be possible.

```
public class BarAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Bar> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Bar bar, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", bar.getId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("name", bar.getName());
        jsonObject.addProperty("foo_id", bar.getFoo().getId());
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Here `foo_id` is used to represent `Foo` entity which would be serialized and which would cause our cyclic referencing problem. Now when we use adapter `Foo` will not be serialized again from `Bar` only its id will be taken and put in `JSON`.
Now we have `Bar` adapter and we can use it to serialize `Foo`. Here is idea:

```
public String getSomething() {
    //getRelevantFoos() is some method that fetches foos from database, and puts them in list
    List<Foo> fooList = getRelevantFoos();

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Bar.class, new BarAdapter());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(fooList);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

One more thing to clarify, `foo_id` is not mandatory and it can be skipped. Purpose of adapter in this example is to serialize `Bar` and by putting `foo_id` we showed that `Bar` can trigger `ManyToOne` without causing `Foo` to trigger `OneToMany` again...

Answer is based on personal experience, therefore feel free to comment, to prove me wrong, to fix mistakes, or to expand answer. Anyhow I hope someone will find this answer useful.

Comment: Defining adapter for handle serialization proecss itself is another way of handling the cyclic dependency. You have option for it though there are other annotations which can prevent happening this instead of writing the adapters.