# How to get around circular references when using Gson?

Tags: java, android, gson, circular-reference, stack-overflow

I am building an Android application, in which I am using Gson to store Object data.
I have a type `Goal` which I am using which has the following properties:

```
private long id;
private String goalName;
private boolean isMainGoal;
private Goal upperLevelGoal;
private Goal mainGoal;
private ArrayList<Goal> subGoals;
private int goalLevel;
private String textViewSubGoalLine;
private ArrayList<UrlComplex> sitesWithinGoal;
```

When using Gson's `toJson()` method, I get a `StackOverflowError`. From what I have read this is because Gson cannot handle circular references -- that is, it cannot perform `toJson()` on my `Goal` or `ArrayList<Goal>` properties.

I understand that I can somehow use TypeToken to get around this issue. ([gson.toJson() throws StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209959/gson-tojson-throws-stackoverflowerror/17659866#17659866)) However, I have read the manual (http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) and I don't really understand how it can be used to do so.

Does anyone know a way to get around using circular references so I can store info in JSON via Gson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeToken` won't help, its not made for that. If you want to handle circular references in Gson, you will need a `TypeAdapterFactory`, but its not simple.

A better approach is probably to parse your JSon with Jackson (but I actually never used this functionality) :
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences