# Stackoverflow while using gson api's

Tags: java, gson, stack-overflow

I am getting stackoverflow error while deserializing java class.

Code

```
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<StorageEntity>>() {}.getType();
List<StorageEntity> logObj = gson.fromJson (dbDocument, listType);
```

When I do gson.fromJson (dbDocument, listType), I am getting below mentioned stack trace.

```
   java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.google.gson.SimpleCharStream.GetImage(SimpleCharStream.java)
        at   com.google.gson.JsonParserTokenManager.jjFillToken(JsonParserTokenManager.java)
```

I have google it and idea that gson is not able to parse long string. Help me to resolve the issue.

Problem is something like this

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=96

but I didn't found any answer.

Comment: Your Json is too large... Increase the stack-size, on console write `export JAVA_OPTS="-xss8m"

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh This a stackoverflow, not an out of memory!

Comment: @GuyBouallet ... And what exactly is stackoverflow ?

Comment: I think the Json is too deeply nested causing the stack to grow of out of allocated memory, increasing the stack memory allocation should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the object you are trying to deserialize have a circular reference. If yes, there will be an infinite loop.

Comment: It work in C#, but not in java when I use fromJson() method of gson.

Comment: Did you mean serialized instead of deserialized?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg sorry. I updated the answer to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I'd rather say your problem is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209959/gson-tojson-throws-stackoverflowerror. However, I have no certitude because I don't see the structure of your object.