# Gson.fromJson() throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, json, gson, stack-overflow

We have this Json:

```
{
    "id": 500,
    "field1": "TESTE",
    "banco": {
        "id": 300,
        "descricao": "BANCO_TESTE"
    },
    "categorias": [
        {
            "id": 300,
            "descricao": "PT",
            "publica": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And my beans:

```
public class Asking implements Serializable {
     private long id;
     private String field1;
     private Bank bank;
     private List<Categoria> categorias;

     //[getters and setters]
}
```

The beans Bank and Categoria:

```
public class Bank implements Serializable {
private Long code;
private Long id;
private String descricao;
//getters and setters
}

public class Categoria implements Serializable {
private Long code;
private Long id;
private String descricao;
private boolean marcada;
private boolean publica;
//getters and setters
}
```

When I call:

```
gson.fromJson(strJson, tokenType);
```

The error appears:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is `tokenType` set to? Please [edit] your code with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this problem. One of two things are wrong here:

1. Your beans are not defined as you say they are. Check to see if they have other fields hidden within the getter and setter method section. [This can happen if you have a circular reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10209959/1768232)

   - You've stated in the comments that this is likely to be your problem. I recommend:

     1. Remove the extra fields from your bean
     2. Create a new class that contains the extra fields, and a field for the `Asking` instance
     3. Deserialize the `Asking` instance using Gson, and then pass it into the new class's constructor.
2. You are doing something unexpected with your setup of the `gson.fromJson` method. Here's what I'm using that works great:

   ```
   public static void parseJSON(String jsonString) {
     Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
     Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Asking>(){}.getType();
     Asking gsonResponse = gsonParser.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
     System.out.println(gsonResponse);
   }
   ```

Either check your bean class definitions for extra fields, or, failing that, try to make your deserialization match mine.

Comment: The beans has anothers fields that strJson no have, its can make a problem?

Comment: @DimmyMagalhães It can if the other field is a circular reference. See the link in #1.

Comment: No have a circular reference.