# gson.toJson() throws StackOverflowError in Servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, json, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have list of objects clients

```
List<Client> clientsList=new ArrayList<Client>();
clientsList=clientDao.GetAllClients();
```

Entity Client has others list as attributes:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private User createdBy;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Clients")
private Set<ClientType> Types=new HashSet();


@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private LeadSource id_LeadSource;
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private Agencie id_Agencie;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="Owner")
private Set<Propertie> properties=new HashSet();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="buyer")
private Set<Sale> sales=new HashSet();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "client")
private Set<Rent> Rents=new HashSet();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "clientDoc")
private Set<Document> Docuements=new HashSet();
```

and when i try to convert list of clients to json format

```
out.write(new Gson().toJson(clientsList));
```

i get this error :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeName(JsonWriter.java:603)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:512)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.write(TypeAdapters.java:270)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.write(TypeAdapters.java:255)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is because your entities have bidirectional connections. So for example `Client` has a set of `Rent`s and each rent has a reference to `Client`. When you try serializing a `Client` you serialize its `Rents` and then you have to serialize each `Client` in `Rent` and so on. This is what causes the `StackOverflowError`.

To solve this problem you will have to mark some properties as `transient` (or use some similar anotation), for example use `transient Client` in `Rent` Then any marshalling lib will just ignore this property.

In case of Gson you can do the other way around marking those field you **do** want to be included in json with `@Expose` and creating the gson object with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

P.S. Also, I would like to mention that converting your JPA entity to json and sending it somewhere is generally not a very good idea. I'd recommend creating a DTO(Data Transfer Object) class where you include only the info you need and ideally using only simple types like `int`, `Date`, `String` and so on. If you have questions about this approach you can google for `DTO`, `Data Transfer Object` or follow this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/transfer_object_pattern.htm

Comment: Thank you very much  @Nestor Sokil for your useful response

Answer (score -1):

After some time fighting with this issue, I believe i have a solution.
As @Nestor Sokil explained problem is in unresolved bidirectional connections, and how to represent connections when they are being serialized.
The way to fix that behavior is to "tell" `gson` how to serialize objects. For that purpose we use `Adapters`.

By using `Adapters` we can tell `gson` how to serialize every property from your `Entity` class as well as which properties to serialize.

Let `Foo` and `Bar` be two entities where `Foo` has `OneToMany` relation to `Bar` and `Bar` has `ManyToOne` relation to `Foo`. We define `Bar` adapter so when `gson` serializes `Bar`, by defining how to serialize `Foo` from perspective of `Bar` cyclic referencing will not be possible.

```
public class BarAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Bar> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Bar bar, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", bar.getId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("name", bar.getName());
        jsonObject.addProperty("foo_id", bar.getFoo().getId());
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Here `foo_id` is used to represent `Foo` entity which would be serialized and which would cause our cyclic referencing problem. Now when we use adapter `Foo` will not be serialized again from `Bar` only its id will be taken and put in `JSON`.
Now we have `Bar` adapter and we can use it to serialize `Foo`. Here is idea:

```
public String getSomething() {
    //getRelevantFoos() is some method that fetches foos from database, and puts them in list
    List<Foo> fooList = getRelevantFoos();

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Bar.class, new BarAdapter());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(fooList);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

One more thing to clarify, `foo_id` is not mandatory and it can be skipped. Purpose of adapter in this example is to serialize `Bar` and by putting `foo_id` we showed that `Bar` can trigger `ManyToOne` without causing `Foo` to trigger `OneToMany` again...

Answer is based on personal experience, therefore feel free to comment, to prove me wrong, to fix mistakes, or to expand answer. Anyhow I hope someone will find this answer useful.

Comment: How about when i serialize your entity, i still get the same problem