# Stack overflow exception when i use strategy for Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

i m trying to save an object to a file as json string ! but when i try to do it without ExclusionStrategy for GsonBuilder it gives me an "duplicated name in Json Exception field hashCode_ in my class" ! i search in google and found a solution that i should use ExclusionStrategy and skip some feilds ! so i did that and i got Stack overflow exception this time ! i dont know what to do and there seems to be no answers to this question on Internet !

this is my convertToJsonString Method :

```
public static <E> String convertToJsonString(E e) {

    ExclusionStrategy strategy = new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            if(f.getName().equals("hashCode_"))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    gson=new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(strategy).create();
    return gson.toJson(e);
}
```

this is where i make JsonElement

```
   public static <E> JsonElement createJsonElement(E e) {
      return gson.toJsonTree(e);
   }
```

and this is where i save my jsonString to a file :

```
   public void writeToFileHotel(Hotel hotel) {

   JsonElement element= JsonUtils.createJsonElement(hotel);
    JsonUtils.writeJsonToFile(element,allGiataHotels_File);
}
```

this is my exception without  ExclusionStrategy

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class 
  ir.viratech.tickbed.model.user.AgencyUser declares multiple JSON fields 
  named hashCode_
```

this is my exception with ExclusionStrategy

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

note : IllegalArgumentException exception accured on JsonElement element= JsonUtils.createJsonElement(hotel)  line

Comment: gson.fromJson(json,JsonElement.class); why u r like this

Comment: is it incorrect ? if it is what is the correct code? @jeevanswamy21

Comment: changed it ot gson.toJsonTree(e) but still the same

Comment: already ur converting then return pass value gson.fromJson(json)

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 yes u r right i corrected it but still getting IllegalArgumentException  declares multiple JSON fields 
  named hashCode_ !!!

Comment: where u declare this one allGiataHotels_File how will u getting

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209959/gson-tojson-throws-stackoverflowerror

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 its final string of my absoluthfile path in my class fields !!

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow error occurs when there is a circular dependency on your object.

You might require to use TypeAdapter