# RealmKotlin gson.toJson() StackOverflowError

Tags: android

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val config = RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(schema = setOf(Book::class))
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .build()
        val realm = Realm.open(configuration = config)

        realm.writeBlocking {
            copyToRealm(Book().apply {
                name = "Book Green"
            })
            copyToRealm(Book().apply {
                name = "Book Blue"
            })
        }

        val list = realm.query<Book>().find()
        Log.i("AOEU", Gson().toJson(list))
    }
}

class Book : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    var name: String = ""
}
```

the Log.i() give me error :

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
> at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:77)
> at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:598)
> at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:409)
> at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:316)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:126)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:244)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:126)

Comment: Tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39670497/9248098

Comment: there is no `realm.copyFromRealm(myObject)` in Realm-Kotlin