# How to save data in activity of later use

Tags: android

I have an `Activity A` that opens `Activity B`. During B's lifecycle, it creates lots of data that is important for later use. When I leave `Activity B`, it gets destroyed. I want that when a user opens B next time, that important data would be restored.

So the question is, how to store that important data?

I had several assumptions:

1. SharedPreferences (`context.getPrecerence(MODE_PRIVATE)`). 
   This is not a good options, because it allows saving only primitive types. I need to save java.io.Serializable object (or at least `Parcelable`).
2. Static variable - not an option. I want my data to remain even if JVM destroys my process when the user navigates to some other app.
3. `Context.openFileOutput()`. Is this OK to make I/O every time I enter activity/quit it?

Something else?

Comment: Many of your options are covered in the Developer's Guide: [Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Just use the database http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: for3st, I am dealing with the binary data, so SQLite is a bad option.
Sam, I've seen this link, but what option from that list do you vote for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save to SharedPreference using `gson.jar`. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15588512/931982) related to this

Comment: Looks nice, is it better than messing around with `openFileInput`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database if the data is user specific.
The database can be accessed whenever user comes back.

Or you can use Bundle (use OnSaveInstance(Bundle)).

[This answer is useful in Bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

Comment: Regarding `OnSaveInstance`
How can this help if I quit activity with `finish()` and when I re-create it again, `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called with `null`?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to retain the data through config changes, `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is what you're looking for. Otherwise, use a database.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

Comment: How can this help if I quit activity with `finish()` and when I re-create it again, `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called with `null`?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` will only work for config changes. You can definitely persist the changes to a file using `openFileOutput`, but using a database _may_ result in quicker I/O. Just make sure the file operations are not performed on the UI thread.