# What is best way to store roughly 200 records in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app, I want to store and read static information for Android permissions. Each permission has three to four attributes (name, short description, detailed description etc.) Earlier, I stored this data in different `.properties` files like each file has (key, value) pairs. But I think, this is really a bad design. I need a new file for each attribute in this case.

File1.properties

```
...
ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION = Allows an application to create mock location providers for testing
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE = Allows applications to access information about networks (Wifi, 3g, 4g)
...
```

So can I use SharedPreferences for this purpose in place of sql database? Other links on SO suggest that I should store only primitive data types in SharedPreferences. Can I use [gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference) to store this information? Can someone please advise me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis sounds like a use for a SQLite database.  You have a large number of rows with fixed data types that you want to be able to retrieve and possibly search.  A database is a perfect fit.