# What to save in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I think there is something I didn't really understand in the onSaveInstanceState mechanism:
I have a class which contains several datas:

```
public class Site implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // used to save device language when the application starts
    private String deviceLanguage;
    private int deviceWifiState;
    private int deviceWifiNetworkId;

    private String localeLanguage;

    // URLs to access various files to describe site and points of interests
    private String wifiSSID = null;
    private String wifiWPAKey = null;
    private String url = null;
    private String flagsDir = "flags/";
    private String flagsUrl = null;
    private String mediasDir = "medias/";
    private String mediasUrl = null;
    private String descriptionFileUrl = null;
    private FragmentActivity activity;

    private ArrayList<Language> listLanguages = null;
    private ArrayList<PointOfInterest> listPointsOfInterest = null;

    ...
    // and some getter/setter
}
```

So the `MainActivity` inflate a `Fragment_init` which starts to fill in the Site class.
Mainly the ArrayList.

This `Fragment_init` is not in the back stack.
When the job is done, it automatically commit() a new `Fragment_selectLanguage` where the user set its language before continuing the initialisation.
Once done, this thread is put in the back stack and a third Fragment_play() in commited.

All fragments implement the following `onsaveInstanceState` method, with the Bundle getted back on their `onViewCreated` method.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);

    saveInstanceState.putSerializable(FRAGMENT_SELECT_LANGUAGE_SITE, (Serializable) site);
}
```

While in the third fragment, if I change the screen orientation then go back to the previous fragment, I get a null pointer exception when it uses listeLanguages, normally initialized in the first fragment, which is null.

When I examine the Site class, I see that most of the datas are inside but some, often the arrays, are null.

What do I miss? I was thinking that the whole Site class was saved !?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in fact I changed Site from Serializable to Parcelable and then that works perfectly using:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
    Log.d("2ndGuide", "MainActivity: onSaveInstanceState");
    saveInstanceState.putParcelable(MAIN_ACTIVITY_SITE, site);
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("2ndGuide", "MainActivity: onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        site = new Site();
    } else {
        site = (Site)savedInstanceState.getParcelable(MAIN_ACTIVITY_SITE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not serialize custom objects.

See this question for exact implementation (Second answer) , [store and retrieve a class object in shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference)

Using a third party import called Gson , https://github.com/pchauhan/StoreandRetrieveObjectClassDemo

Comment: Thanks @Alex I'd rather not spend a large chunk of my time developing such a feature for a tiny part of my project.