# Saving list adapter data on Activity onStop()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have this Activity with a List Fragment which loads data from server if adapter is empty. When i press the back button or go to another activity and back to this activity with Up button, the adapter is reset to empty.

So how can i save the adapter data, so the activity doesn't have to load data from the server all the time?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Sorry i don't provide any code. I just want to know the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the data into local SQlite DB, and read and show it onResume().

Answer (score 0):

Save the arraylist object which you are passing to adapter. Save it in your parent activity and get it while setting the adapter yo listview.

Use *getter* and *setter* in Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question is answered here, check this answer by Parag Chauhan
[Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference)