# How can I save & retrieve JSON array in Android local storage?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to save JSON array to local storage in Android and I can't retrieve it

```
//that to send Json array to shared preferences 
save.edit().putString("courses", courses.toString()).apply();
//that to retrieve it
    String jsonObject = PreferenceManager.
            getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("courses","");
```

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: You can look into this **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15588512/2065039)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store and retrieve a class object in shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference)